# Is there any difference between $@ and "$@"?

Tags: bash, expansion

Is there any difference between `$@` and `"$@"`?

I understand there may be differences for non special characters, but what about the `@` sign with input arguments?

Comment: The question is not a strict duplicate, but the answers there also answer this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes!

```
$ cat a.sh
echo "$@"
echo $@
```

Let's run it:

```
$ ./a.sh 2 "3     4" 5
2 3     4 5                  # output for "$@"
2 3 4 5                      # output for $@  -> spaces are lost!
```

As you can see, using `$@` makes the parameters to "lose" some content when used as a parameter. See -for example- [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/1983854) for a detailed explanation of this.

---

From [GNU Bash manual --> 3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html):

> **@**
>
> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. **When
>   the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word**. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Answer (score 7):

Passing $@ to a command passes all arguments to the command. If an argument contains a space the command would see that argument as two separate ones.

Passing "$@" to a command passes all arguments as quoted strings to the command. The command will see an argument containing whitespace as a single argument containing whitespace.

To easily visualize the difference write a function that prints all its arguments in a loop, one at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash

loop_print() {
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        echo "argument: '$1'"
        shift
    done
}

echo "#### testing with \$@ ####"
loop_print $@
echo "#### testing with \"\$@\" ####"
loop_print "$@"
```

Calling that script with

```
<script> "foo bar"
```

will produce the output

```
#### testing with $@ ####
argument: 'foo'
argument: 'bar'
#### testing with "$@" ####
argument: 'foo bar'
```